# Row_Number not working in webmatrix

Tags: webmatrix, row-number

I am using webmatrix to display some data in a page.
This query works fine in sql server 2008 but not in WebMatrix.

```
select row_number() over (order by title) as SNO, title from movies
```

Error: "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 21,Token in error = over ]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen if you are using SQL CE as your database in WebMatrix. SQL CE does not support the OVER keyword. Migrate the SQL CE database you are using in WebMatrix to SQL Server by clicking on the "Migrate" button. Then it will start working.